# Instagram ?_a=1 API JSON not working anymore

Tags: javascript, python, api, instagram

Recently, I have noticed that adding ?_a=1 at the end of an Instagram user's name no longer returns a JSON object that describes the information on the page.

For example: [https://www.instagram.com/{username}/feed/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/feed/?__a=1)
The link used to return a large JSON object about each post.

Was this removed by Instagram or is it just me? Also is there a stronger alternative to be able to read post data from a user without having the be signed in to their account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on other answers to the same question, it looks like the feed works intermittently for years.

I tried `/channel/` instead of `/feed/` as others suggested, but the same error persisted.

Some suggest it's an invalid user agent header that causes issues.

This API URL I found from an XHR request when logged in also returns a user agent error if accessed directly.

[https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/fbsearch/accounts_recs/{username}](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/fbsearch/accounts_recs/%7Busername%7D)

```
{"message":"useragent mismatch","status":"fail"}
```